# Associate rdls with a new data source

Tags: sql, reporting-services, rdl

I have about 300 some reports, and the data source has been deleted during migration, so the dependency of the reports from the data source has been lost.
how can I re-associate the new data source I created to all the reports without manually going to each report and setting the data source in it.

Comment: Been a while but if my memory serves me, the reports are all xml behind the scenes... should just be able to manipulate the xml using your preferred method

Comment: Also, seeing as you are changing them all anyway, consider changing the datasource to a shared datasource on the server so that if you ever have to change it again, you can just it in the one place.

Comment: what `data source` you have used `embedded` or `shared`

Comment: im using a shared data source though.

Answer (score 0):

There is one way to solve this issue,

1. Before that you wants to rember that you know the Datasource name you given to the rdl files,
2. You wants to create new datasource in your RDL,
3. And then you can deploy your datasource in your Reportserver.

Thats it.